# acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ambassador

I am trying to figure out how to setup Ambassador on Kubernetes and I am hitting some walls.

Our app is hosted on DogitalOcean and we are trying to use their resources in full. They have a nice starter kit to get the environment up and running. the part I am stuck on is setting up Ingress Controller. We choose Ambassador for this purpose and here are the docs related to it: https://github.com/digitalocean/Kubernetes-Starter-Kit-Developers/blob/main/03-setup-ingress-controller/ambassador.md#step-2---defining-the-hosts-for-ambassador-edge-stack

I installed the Ambassador itself without issues (almost). Next was to set a host.

Here is my host file:

```
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Host
metadata:
  name: priz-api-host
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  hostname: api.priz.guru
  acmeProvider:
    email: alex@priz.guru
  tlsSecret:
    name: tls2-cert
  requestPolicy:
    insecure:
      action: Redirect
      additionalPort: 8080
```

Note: the docs mention that the hostname must be accessible from the internet, and it is.

After applying the changes, and describing the host I am getting the following error:

```
Normal   Pending  49m (x2 over 49m)  Ambassador Edge Stack  performing ACME challenge for tlsSecret "tls2-cert"."ambassador" (hostnames=["apii.priz.guru"])...
  Warning  Error    48m                Ambassador Edge Stack  obtaining tlsSecret "tls2-cert"."ambassador" (hostnames=["apii.priz.guru"]): acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:
[apii.priz.guru] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from http://apii.priz.guru/.well-known/acme-challenge/e9cme4KfsSovEz_jpjCKTskamm7bpn4Lw8I6JJBaprk [157.230.204.38]: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>", url:
  Normal   Pending  43m (x2 over 43m)  Ambassador Edge Stack  (combined from similar events): performing ACME challenge for tlsSecret "tls2-cert"."ambassador" (hostnames=["api.priz.guru"])...
  Warning  Error    43m                Ambassador Edge Stack  obtaining tlsSecret "tls2-cert"."ambassador" (hostnames=["api.priz.guru"]): acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:
[api.priz.guru] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from https://api.priz.guru/.well-known/acme-challenge/sDf1glecKdXnV7HYrWuYzpnCoFOJHYW7Kk0jyDBlxwA [2606:4700:3033::6815:1056]: 404, url:
  Warning  Error  32m  Ambassador Edge Stack  obtaining tlsSecret "tls2-cert"."ambassador" (hostnames=["api.priz.guru"]): acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:
[api.priz.guru] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from https://api.priz.guru/.well-known/acme-challenge/Pob867AOqpWS_rws_hB9EGqsZPLCInPDp1dDa2hWGAI [2606:4700:3036::ac43:d279]: 404, url:
  Normal   Pending  11m (x2 over 32m)  Ambassador Edge Stack  tlsSecret "tls2-cert"."ambassador" (hostnames=["api.priz.guru"]): needs updated: tlsSecret does not exist
  Normal   Pending  11m (x2 over 32m)  Ambassador Edge Stack  performing ACME challenge for tlsSecret "tls2-cert"."ambassador" (hostnames=["api.priz.guru"])...
  Warning  Error    11m                Ambassador Edge Stack  obtaining tlsSecret "tls2-cert"."ambassador" (hostnames=["api.priz.guru"]): acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:
[api.priz.guru] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from https://api.priz.guru/.well-known/acme-challenge/834gr6TLzUCDq1-j2qvdWMCeMVFSQD3U41EgE57UrbY [2606:4700:3033::6815:1056]: 404, url:
```

Now, digging into the docs a bit more, I tried to understand what is [HTTP-01 Challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge). In fact, this kind of endpoint does not exist on the current server.

I am confused, What needs to be done to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I resolved it myself (not 100% sure if correctly).
Apparently, the hostname has to be pointed to the Ambassador's public IP. As the Ambassador is the one responsible for verifying the cert.

Comment: yes you are right, if you are using the HTTP-01 in DNS-01 you need to keep DNS record in provider side